# Windows UI Automation double click mouse

Tags: c#, windows, winapi, ui-automation

I'm currently using the following code to double click a mouse button.

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
public static extern void mouse_event(uint dwFlags, uint dx, uint dy, uint cButtons, uint dwExtraInfo);

public static void DoubleClick(AutomationElement element)
{
                Point p = element.GetClickablePoint();
                Cursor.Position = new System.Drawing.Point((int)p.X, (int)p.Y);
                mouse_event(0x02 | 0x04, (uint)p.X, (uint)p.Y, 0, 0);
                mouse_event(0x02 | 0x04, (uint)p.X, (uint)p.Y, 0, 0);
}
```

However, I believe this is leaving resources open that causes my automated tests to not exit cleanly, causing crashes. Plus, it requires the mouse to be actually be on the clickable point, which has the potential to cause issue if the tester moves the mouse at the wrong time. Is there a better was to do this?

Comment: With UI Automation, you don't think in terms of mouse events, you think in terms of actions. What are you trying to double-click, and what does double-clicking do?

Comment: I'm trying to double click a row in a data grid, which opens a window I need to interact with.

Comment: Then the equivalent would be to navigate to that row and column in the data grid and "activate" it, assuming double click is mapped to activation. If not, substitute the proper action verb. This is the API to start with: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.automation.gridpattern(v=vs.110).aspx